# DC is trying to communicate with unknown servers using DCOM

Tags: dcom

Event viewer on my DC has new error every few seconds saying "DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer *ip address* using any of the configured protocols."
Non of the IP addresses in any of the errors are known to us, non of them in the domain.
AD is pretty clean, after latest maintenance.

Any idea how to get rid of these errors?

Thank you